# Installing pycurl with 'fatal error: gnutls/gnutls.h: No such file or directory'

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, pycurl

I use ubuntu 16.04 and python 2.7.12.

When I try to install pycurl with pip, I could see below log.

```
aaa@bbb:~/git/ccc$ sudo pip install pycurl
  Downloading pycurl-7.43.0.tar.gz (182kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 184kB 515kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pycurl
  Running setup.py install for pycurl ... error

...

    In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:0:
    src/pycurl.h:173:30: fatal error: gnutls/gnutls.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
```

How to install pycurl with above log?

Answer (score 38):

Install gnutls first using:

```
sudo apt-get install libgnutls28-dev
```

Then try again.

Comment: I faced the same problem on mint 19.1. apt-get install'ing the libgnutls28-dev package helped resolve the problem.


After adding the above package, was able to get pycurl installed and functioning in a venv with the following command: 

`pip install --compile --no-cache-dir --global-option="--with-gnutls" pycurl`

Comment: Thanks ! This is still relevant with Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.8 and PyCURL 7.45

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer by myself.

Need to install libgnutls28-dev like below first.

```
sudo apt-get install libgnutls28-dev
```